# Creating Images from Tableviews in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uitableview, ios5

I have a core data app that displays a tableview of named individuals from a database. Selection of the individuals provides a detailed view of their characteristics. Would it be possible to create images of each of the detailed tableviews for viewing in an image carousel. I think I could manage the carousel part (examples on github) but I am struggling with finding out how to create the actual images. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question Old Dog! It would help if you let us know what platform you're developing your app for and which language(s) you're using :)

Comment: Hi - Sorry, making assumptions again. Platform is iOS5 for iPhone created using Xcode 4.2

Comment: Outside of my area of expertise I'm afraid, but I've changed your tags to hopefully get this question some better exposure. Always good practice to include the tags for your development language and any frameworks you're drawing from (as long as they're applicable to your question, that is) :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an image from tableView? If you are using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) , it provides you with instances of `UIView`, and tableView inherits from that, so you should be able to get the view of a tableView and show it there. You can also create a custom view and add it to the iCarousel.